Ubuntu allows user to sudo without password even though it's not allowed + missing crontabs
1 - Problem with unprotected sudo
I have an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS server that runs for a few years non stop. I didn't notice anything strange during that time, as well as I didn't change any server's configuration/packages/authentication recently.
Today I logged in to the server via SSH and when I executed sudo su -, it allowed me to become root without asking for password. That's weird, because I was always prompted for the password when executing sudo .... I checked /etc/sudoers and /etc/sudoers.d/* and those files are default, nothing/noone changed them. How is it possible?
auth.log says:
Jun 21 00:05:48 srv1 sudo: fred: TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/fred ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su -
Jun 21 00:05:48 srv1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by fred(uid=1000)
Jun 21 00:05:48 srv1 su: (to root) root on pts/1
Jun 21 00:05:48 srv1 su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by fred(uid=0)

2 - Problem with missing crontabs (but still being executed somehow)
I don't know if it's related, but I also noticed other strange behaviour of my system. I have a few cronjobs executed as root. That jobs are regularly executed without any issues. But today I wanted to change something in crontab configuration and... Ubuntu said that root user doesn't have any cronjobs configured. How is it possible, if the jobs are still being executed? Where are they stored then? I can still see in syslog, that crons are executed successfully, but I can't edit/disable them.
root@srv1:~# crontab -l
root@srv1:~#

I've checked raw crontab files in /var/spool/cron, but I didn't find my cronjobs.
root@srv1:~# ls -la /var/spool/cron/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 Feb 17  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 Apr 18  2023 ..
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 4096 Jun 21 00:11 crontabs

root@srv1:~# ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs/
total 16
drwx-wx--T 2 root     crontab 4096 Jun 21 00:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root    4096 Feb 17  2023 ..
-rw------- 1 root     crontab  212 Jun 21 00:12 root
-rw------- 1 fred     crontab 1447 Jun 20 23:29 fred

In fact, I found root's crontab file, but it seems like some default content:
root@srv1:~# cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Fri Jun 21 00:12:46 2024)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
11 * * * * /root/.config/cron/perfcc

Now it's the time for my questions:

how is it possible that Ubuntu allows me to become root without asking for password (even though I'm not in sudoers)?
why Ubuntu thinks, that my root user doesn't have any crobjobs configured, but they're still being executed?

Thank you in advance :)

11 * * * * /root/.config/cron/perfcc doesn't look like default content - what does the file contain? As well, root may have jobs in the systemwide crontab file /etc/crontab.
